If $0\to A'\stackrel{i}{\to} A\stackrel{p}{\to} A''\to 0$ is exact and $i\simeq0,p\simeq0$, then $A\simeq0$
Let $0\to A'\stackrel{i}{\to} A\stackrel{p}{\to} A''\to 0$ be an exact sequence of chain complexes (general modules, no specific assumptions) and $i,p$ are null-homotopic chain maps, how do I show $A$ is contractible? I've considered two possibilities:

Because the maps are null-homotopic, by the long exact sequence it follows that $A$ is acyclic, so by a different result it's enough to show that $A$-cycles are complemented submodules, however I don't see where to start with that.
I've tried constructing an explicit contraction, however I must be missing something because the usual diagram chasing doesn't work. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the homotopies for $i$ and $p$, the obvious thing seems to be to push $x\in A_n$ via $\beta$ to $A''_{n+1}$ and to take a $p$-preimage, however I don't know how to make this well-defined.

To clarify, this is an exercise in Dold's "Algebraic Topology" (pg. 26, exercise 4*), but the complexes there are of abelian groups, perhaps this doesn't hold for arbitrary modules (I had assumed it does).

For starters, do you actually know that it is true? Is it mentioned somewhere? My gut feeling is that this only holds when the sequence splits (up to homotopy).

@MartinBrandenburg it's stated as an exercise in Dold's "Algebraic Topology" (pg. 26, exercise 4*). In the exercise it's stated for complexes of abelian groups, but I assumed (perhaps falsely) that it must hold in general as well.

@St.Barth Hang on: if you’re working with algebraic topology, very possibly these complexes in question are free Abelian complexes, bounded from below. Is my hunch right? This is key. In this case it’s true, but I think it’s difficult or possibly false otherwise.

@FShrike you're right of course, but I was hoping to prove it in maximal generality for my own satisfaction. At the very least, if the book is to be believed, it should hold for all abelian complexes, not just free ones.

So are the abelian groups free or not?

@MartinBrandenburg They had better be: and more strongly than that, the complexes had better be K-projective (or similar), e.g. bounded complexes of free Abelian groups. I believe I have found a counterexample

@MartinBrandenburg nowhere in the exercise is that stated, so I'd say no. Perhaps it was left out by accident?

This is false! But true in nice contexts, see below.
Depending on how much homological algebra you know, the following may or may not make sense (but at the end you find a criterion for when it is true and an explicit counterexample otherwise):

Conceptually, the difficulty is this: you have presented a distinguished triangle in the derived category, with homotopically (so certainly in the derived category) zero maps, and this concludes the middle object is zero (acyclic); you want to lift these conclusions up to the triangulated homotopy category, but can’t immediately do so since an exact sequence of complexes does not induce a distinguished triangle in the homotopy category; the chain map $C(i)\to A’’$ is a quasiisomorphism but not a homotopy equivalence, in general. Despite the fact $i,p$ are zero in the homotopy category, we cannot lift the problem ‘upstairs’. UNLESS, we are so lucky that all the complexes involved are semiprojective (what the Stacks project calls K-projective) e.g. bounded complexes of free Abelian groups such as what you might encounter in algebraic topology; then the quasiisomorphism $C(i)\to A’’$ can indeed be lifted to a homotopy equivalence, so you can invert along it and infer $A\to C(i)$ is nullhomotopic, and we can proceed with an argument.

An explicit counterexample: let $A$ be the complex $\cdots\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\overset{0}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb Z\overset{2}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb Z\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to\cdots$, cyclically repeating itself. Here, $\pi$ is the canonical projection. Let $A’$ be the subcomplex $\cdots\to0\to\Bbb Z\overset{2}{\to}2\Bbb Z\to0\to\cdots$; we may then identify $A’’$ as $\cdots\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to0\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\overset{=}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to\cdots$. The indexing is such that the “$\cdots$” at the start and end of all three sketches are aligned.
You can explicitly check that $i,p$ are nullhomotopic, that all complexes are acyclic ($A’$ and $A’’$ are also contractible, which abstractly proves $i,p$ are nullhomotopic, and which drives home the point that lifting from the derived to the homotopy category is difficult even in the presence of strong assumptions) yet $A$ is not contractible.
So indeed $0\to A\to B\to C\to0$ can be short exact, with $A,C$ contractible, with $B$ noncontractible - merely acyclic.

I do not think you need to "repeat" anything in your construction (and your long complex splits into a bunch of SES connected by zeroes anyways). Indeed, SES $2Z \to Z \to Z/2$ is an extension of its kernel ($2Z \to 2Z \to 0$) and cokernel ($0 \to Z/2 \to Z/2$); inclusion of lhs and projection to rhs are nullhomotopic as they factor through identity on them, which is nullhomotopic, and SES itself is not contractible as it is equivalent to being split.
